# My SceneBuilder system font is too hard to read

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

My SceneBuilder suddenly changed the system/default font to an italic font that is to hard for me to read. How can I fix it? This happened when I click on Set Gluon Theme, but when I go back to Modena theme, the font doesn't change.I have already uninstalled and then reinstalled it but nothing happened.

[image]

How to get back to the default font?

Comment: What version? Any luck with File > Preferences > Reset? On MacOS? Consider a look at `com.gluonhq.scenebuilder.plist` in `~/Library/Preferences` or [_Ask Different_](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I've reset but nothing happened, seems like the default system font has changed

Comment: I actually think one of the Windows updates caused this. I have experienced a similar font change in many different applications.

Comment: Does uninstalling scene builder, and then reinstalling the most recent stable version fix the issue?

Comment: @SedJ601 The image looks like a Mac screenshot.  So the issue could not be caused by a Windows update.

Comment: @jewelsea, Good catch. I did experience something very similar, and the font looks the same, but I haven't updated or installed `SceneBuilder` lately.  My machine is a Windows machine, though.